# Generic Term for Professional vs Amateur

Tags: single-word-requests

In ballroom competitions, events are listed as in the following example:

> Amateur Adult Bronze International Standard Waltz/Quickstep.

I can break this down except for the first bit as:

- [??? (Amateur)]
- [Age Division (Adult)]
- [Level (Bronze)]
- [Style (International Standard)]
- [Dances (Waltz/Quickstep)].

What would be a good term to describe the first bit of the event description?

If it helps, the options for the first block are:

- 'Amateur'
- 'Professional'
- 'Pro-Am' (wherein a professional and an amateur compete together)
- 'Teacher/Student'.

Comment: 'Status' will probably do, though it is of course a rank hypernym.

Comment: Aliden I may have got slightly carried away with reformatting. If you prefer the original feel free to revert my edits !

Comment: 'Relation' (as in: the participant's relation to dancing) is more descriptive than 'category'. I would consider using 'pursuit' (if he/she pursues it as a hobby or otherwise) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Category. Category seems to be a little more generic occasionally, but it is the predominate word for "Amateur", "Pro-Am", "Professional", etc.

"Pro-Am competition is a category in DanceSport ..." [The Ballroom Dance Company](http://www.theballroomdancecompany.com/ProAmCompetition.shtml)

"Pro-am is a category in dancesport competitions ..." [Ball Room Boston](http://ballroominboston.com/competitive-dancers-faqs) [Starry Night Dance Studio](http://www.starrynightdancestudio.com/competitive-dance.html)

"... the group will be moved to the PROFESSIONAL OR PRO AM category ..." [Love 2 Dance Competition](http://www.luv2dancecompetition.com/levels-categories)

"[AMATEUR] category" "PROFESSIONAL category" [Fusion Dance Contest](http://fusiondancecontest.com/en/competition-rules/)

"Pro Am: Any teacher or professional dancer may perform in this category." [The Dance Out](http://www.thedanceout.com/rules)

Comment: This is what I came up with via some off-site discussions as well. If nothing better comes along in the next several hours, I'll mark this as the answer.